# Touch events for fullcalendar.js

Tags: fullcalendar, hammer.js

I am trying to use fullcalendar.js library with mobile capability.
Previous versions were depending on jqueryui, so jQuery UI Touch Punch would have worked but now they removed the dependency.
I was wondering if anybody already implemented drag or resize event for mobile with this library.
In particular, is it possible to drag with Hammer.js?